# Connect iPhone screen as camera without QuickTime

Tags: macos, iphone, screen-capture, streaming

I'm trying to stream my iPhone screen and the usual approach is mirroring it to QuickTime via the "New Movie Recording" option (without actually pressing the record button), and then streaming QuickTime's window with [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com) via the "Window capture" source.

However, OBS has really high CPU consumption when streaming windows due to the "inefficiencies in Apple's window capture API" according to the [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/2841#issuecomment-732987122).

Is it possible to present iPhone screen as a camera to macOS without QuickTime, so I can use the "Video Capture Device" source directly?

[image]

Comment: Can you run the more efficient 24.0.6 build of OBS?

Comment: @bmike hope so, I'm on Big Sur already and unsure if older versions of the app support it well. Still, having QuickTime as an intermediate step feels excessive, would be cool if there was some utility to mirror iOS screen to macOS video input.